# Naming conventions for table columns? How do you do it?

Tags: database, database-design

Are their moments in your professional experience in which stepping away from rigid naming convention structures (like the one's suggested [here](http://www.interaktonline.com/support/articles/details/Design+Your+Database-Database+Naming+Convention.html?id_art=24&id_asc=221)), or the prefix naming conventions discussed in other stack overflow questions.

To something more simplified as depicted in the image. In this simplified depiction of dogs, people, and the relation of what type of dogs a person owns. The relation table is using column names that can be sorta read out in a fashion that immediately and comprehensively explains their resulting actions.

Now as the famous programming adage goes "it depends". I expect that to be the case, but I wanted to hear from professionals in the field if there is a push for some sense of consensual unwavering standard, designed to be sufficient, comprehensive, regardless of project scope size.

[image: simple naming convention]

Comment: Voting to close - it's going to incite a religious war. There's no "One True Way" of naming anything in the programming world. Everyone's got their opinion, and everyone else is of the opinion that everyone else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would in general say that is a poor idea. You would have develoeprs who would not understand easily that this_person_id = id_person or owns_dog_type_id = id_dog_type so it can create a manitenance issue and yet I don't see that as easier to understand than id_person = id_person and  id_dog_type =  id_dog_type.

What is a SQL antipattern, and that you should not use, is ID for the inital id in every table.   It can create bugs in developing long complex queries and problems in reporting and is in general a poor idea. It is an even worse choice in a database that allows natural joins as you might end up with the id inteh people table joined to the id in the pets table

Comment: So you are in disarrangement with "Shark"'s answer when he states that tables that contain a PK should be labeled as simply "ID". Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: fwiw - i agree with @HLGEM that the id only column name introduces opportunity for errors.

Comment: @Ealianis, yes, ID is an antipattern.

Answer (score 2):

in the relation table, i think it is poor form to impose a meaning on the relationship via those column names.  instead i think it preferable to include a ROLE column to identify the relationship between the items.

for instance, the role might be OWNS, or the role might be WALKS, or the role might be GROOMS.  Also, good practice to include dates on these relations. so with a simple change (add role, and some dates) this table is now static, and the uses are data driven, not encumbered by column names.

this basic model will work on almost any relation, so is therefore a great pattern to adopt.  It is also a driving metaphor for newer data management idioms like Semantic Ontologies, where you want the ROLE to act like a predicate in the triple.

my 2 cents :)

Comment: +1 when two identifying columns have the same name in different tables, it is much easier for future developers to know immediately ther is a relationship between them. Especially as you have many tables. So id_person means exactly the same field everywhere and you wil find it easier to skip joins you don't need. Adding Roles in a joining table is quite handy as you suggest.